# How to change the tax from 18% to 21% without changing prices

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop

I want to change the tax from 18% to 21% in my Prestashop. But I don't want to change the prices, I only want to show were it has to put 18%, the new IVA. For example, at the PDF invoice.

I changed all the strings for the 18% tax to "21 TAX" and it works at backend, but when, for example, PDF invoice seems to take the numeric value and I want to change that.

The file is classes/pdf.php

Any idea?

NEW: Code is too long, stackoverflow doesn't allow me to copy here the code. Here it is http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3915869/PDF.php

Comment: Vote for people that do not raise taxes.

Comment: Now you have the code ;)

Comment: I meant just post the relevant bits.

Comment: There's no 18% not 21% in that file and it's not clear to me where that number comes from or what you want to change.

Comment: If you want to lower the price ex tax to get the same price including tax, you can just take the price ex tax, multiply by 1.18 to get the price including tax, then divide by 1.21 to get the new, lower price, excluding vat. But I'm not sure if I understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the kind of thing that should be in a config file. I'm looking at line 666:

```
Configuration::get('PS_TAX')
```

Maybe change the value of PS_TAX in the config file?

Comment: See, configurations files are evil.